# radio button can't be clicked by firefox driver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

There is strange problem, in firefox 16, and selenuim webdriver 2.26.0, radio button not had been clicked, after:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("path_to_radio_button")).click();
```

There are no exceptions, but not result too.
In Chrome it been clicked.

What can help to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using an XHTML doctype?

Comment: Try with Selenium 2.27.0 and then try to provide a test case for us, please. Can you give us the URL of the page? Can you make a simplified HTML document showing the problem? I just tried with a quick test and it of course can click a radio button.

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't provide you URL, but I can say, that it is ok with Chrome. Radiobutton not selected before this operation. I just don't know, how i can solve this problem. With javascriptExecutor with:
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return document.getElementByXpath("+ "//li/span[contains(text(), 'this case')]" +").click()");

Comment: and get error - "missing arguments"

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
IWebElement radio = driver.FindElement(By.ID(//radiobutton id));
  if(radio.Selected)
 {
    //do something here.
  }
```

or

```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @value='Radio2']")).isSelected();
```

Comment: Good luck. If this answer solved your problem then don't forgot to accept and give up-vote

Comment: Thank you, but it was first of all, that i started to do for solving, no I don't try to click selected button, and if after i try driver.findElement(By.xpath("path_to_radio_button")).isSelected it returns false. On firefox.

Comment: Instead of `.isselected` used `.selected` and then check and let me know it work or not?

Comment: Sorry, but it is the same thing, guy)
It depends from you current implementation, from objects(.IsSelected) or creating interfaces (.Selected).

Comment: in this huge system i couldn't change realization on new instance of WebDriver.